# jquery insert html between elements multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

I have multiple divs in my htmlthat needs to have an element added between the div and p

```
<div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all">
 <p><b>Reversed</b></p>
</div>
```

what i want is the html to add the a span between the two

```
<div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all">
<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
 <p><b>Reversed</b></p>
</div>
```

But the functions ive tried have not been able to do this for each class once, if there are  13 classes, the function puts 13 s on each of the 13 classes, regardless if i just use a selector or an each(), insertBefore(), before(), after(), ect

here is what ive tried that hasnt worked

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
       $(function () {                 
html = '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>';

           $('.ui-state-error').each(function(i){
                $('.ui-state-error').eq(i).before('p').append(html);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/fXpBe/3/)**

```
     $(function () {                 
html = '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;">your span</span>';

           $('.ui-state-error').each(function(i){
                $(this).prepend(html);           
            });

        });​
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to do this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    html = '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>';
    $('.ui-state-error').prepend(html);
});
```

Here is the documentation about [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: it still adds the element multiple times per class, and erases the existing <p> , i havent been able to figure out how to iterate through each class and add an element between elements

Comment: It should, i've just tried this. Be sure the code is not executed many times !

Comment: the code is being executed multiple times , wasnt the append or prepend executing multiple, the code was. thank you

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you:

`$(function(){
html = '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>';
    $(html).prependTo('.ui-state-error');
});`

My answer is similar with PoulsQ's. But the different is $.prepend() is for only one matched element (I think that is the first matched element), while $.prependTo() is prepending to all matched elements. This rule is also worked for append() and appendTo(); before() and insertBefore(); after() and insertAfter();

Hope this can be helpful.